# Слитное и раздельное написание "насколько"

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Предложение "На сколько он старше своей сестры?"

Уместно ли в нём написать "на сколько" слитно? Ведь необязательно спрашивают о количестве лет, а хотят узнать степень разницы в возрасте. Можно заменить на "В какой мере он старше своей сестры?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Возможны оба варианта:** Насколько он старше своей сестры? На сколько он старше своей сестры?

**Из словарей:**

**НАСКОЛЬКО.** I. **местоим. нареч.** В какой мере, степени. Н. помню, это произошло десять лет назад. Н. этот фильм лучше! Н. здесь теплее! **Но числит**. на сколько (на сколько дней).

Если "насколько/на сколько" относится к прилагательным, имеющим значение количественной оценки, то здесь, скорее всего,  **возможны оба варианта (авторское решение):**

**1) Числительное "на сколько":**

Но он справился, не дал этой мысли развиться далеко — стоп, для чего не годится? **на сколько старше?** И переспросил сразу: давно закончила? [Майя Кучерская. Тетя Мотя // «Знамя», 2012].

**2) Наречие степени**

Все женщины расселись на веранде, смотрели им вслед и мирно сплетничали. ― Интересно, она его **насколько младше**? ― спросила Антонина. [Маша Трауб. Домик на Юге (2009)].

**Насколько больше** нам придется платить за те же некачественные и нерегулярные услуги?

Он поверил и теперь каждое утро меряет, **насколько длиннее** стала растительность над его бледными губами. [А. П. Чехов. Драма на охоте (1884)]

Answer (score 5):

Написание и интонация здесь зависят от того, насколько конкретный ожидается ответ: если вопрос подразумевает количество лет, то нужно писать раздельно, а в устной форме при таком упрощении (слово "лет" опущено) желательно сделать акцент на слове "сколько", хотя это и не гарантирует конкретного ответа. Если же интересуются приблизительным соотношением возраста людей (вдруг она ему в дочки годится и т. п.), то значение - "в какой мере" и написание слитное; в этом случае при произнесении можно не выделять слов (любой ответ устроит говорящего).