# На сколько / насколько ты опоздаешь?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Мы ввека / в века останемся друзьями!

> На сколько / насколько ты опоздаешь?

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430903/Слитное-и-раздельное-написание-насколько/430904#430904  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476080/Насколько-на-сколько/476081#476081

Comment: ввека / в века  нет таких слов, проверяйте по словарю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Насколько / на сколько](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476080/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be)

Comment: Нет  слова ввека.  И нет сочетания  "останемся в века". Закрывать надо неграмотные вопросы, а не оставлять открытыми.

Answer (score 1):

"Мы в (долгие) века останемся друзьями!" – можно вставить прилагательное, можно склонять "мы в веках останемся друзьями!", [значит существительное с предлогом, раздельно](https://grammatika-rus.ru/razlichenie-narechij-i-sushhestvitelnyh-s-predlogom-2/).

"На сколько ты опаздываешь?" ответ на вопрос будет "на пятнадцать минут", то есть задается вопрос к местоимению по сути "На *сколько* ты опаздываешь?". "На *какое количество минут* ты опаздываешь?".

Может ли быть это наречием "насколько"? Теряется весь смысл, если предположим его употребление и попробуем заменить на какой-нибудь синоним: "Как ты опаздываешь?" – "С упреками совести." :) "Как долго ты опаздываешь?" – "Последние пять лет все время опаздываю, не могу себя взять в руки".

P.S. [Здесь еще пишут](https://mel.fm/gramotnost/kak-pisat/7128409-na-skolko-ili-naskolko-kogda-slovo-nuzhno-pisat-slitno-a-kogda--net), что если можно подставить "подразумеваемое зависимое слово", то значит предлог с местоимением, хотел бы я увидеть полное правило про это.

Answer (score 0):

На какое количество времени = на сколько. Если речь о времени, то пишется раздельно, так как в таких случаях слово является числительным с предлогом "на".

> насколько, нареч. (насколько можно судить), но числит. на сколько (на
> сколько дней)